# How to build a table with kableExtra with summarized months but not summarize the values of the other columns

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I want to have a table that contains all my columns.

The dataframe looks like this:

[image: dataframe]

So I want a table that just shows the state, party, population, cases, deaths, cases/100K.
without the Date but with the values from the latest Day in the Dataset, which would be today the 2020-09-29.

I tried it like this:

```
corona_cases_month <- corona_party_states %>% group_by(state, Party, Date=floor_date(Date)) %>% rename("Population"=totalPopulation, "Confirmed Cases"=totalConfirmed, "Confirmed Deaths"=totalDeaths, "Cases/100K"=CasesPop)

corona_cases_month %>%
kbl() %>%
  kable_paper("hover", full_width = F) %>%
    kable_styling(fixed_thead = T) %>%
   column_spec(1, bold = T, border_right = T) %>%
column_spec(6, bold = T, color = "orange")
```

but it's not the right outcome because it still shows every date in a new row.

I tried it with the floor function before and it worked - but I used summarize and of course the values of population, cases, deaths than were all wrong:

[image: tableoutput]

How can I build this table with only the values from yesterday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend filtering the data to only keep the rows with the last date. I wouldn't try to create a new variable in the `group_by` instead do it in a `mutate`. This is one way:

```
corona_cases_month <- corona_party_states %>% 
  group_by(state, Party) %>% 
  mutate(Date_new=floor_date(Date)) %>% 
  filter(Date == Date_new) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(state, Party, Date_new) %>%
  rename("Population"=totalPopulation, "Confirmed Cases"=totalConfirmed, "Confirmed Deaths"=totalDeaths, "Cases/100K"=CasesPop)
```

Comment: I tried this code now but the Date_new column is just the same as the Date column. Also unfortunately the table looks still the same.

Comment: ok, now it works. 
```
corona_cases_month <- corona_party_states %>% 
  group_by(state, Party) %>% 
  mutate(Date_new=floor_date(Date, unit = "month")) %>% 
  filter(Date == Date_new) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(state, Party, Date_new) %>%
  rename("Population"=totalPopulation, "Confirmed Cases"=totalConfirmed, "Confirmed Deaths"=totalDeaths, "Cases/100K"=CasesPop) %>% select(-Date)
```
I added a unit specification and the select function. Now I have it by month, which is great! But how do I tell the kable function that I only want the last month (september) in the table?

Comment: ok I figured it out again, I added:
filter(Date_new >= as.Date('2020-09-01') & Date_new <= as.Date('2020-09-29'))

Thank you so much for your help!